# Postgres docker "User "postgres" has no password assigned."

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I am running a Postgres image using docker. It used to run without any problems on both Windows10 and Ubuntu 18.04.

After recloning the project on the Ubuntu system, it gives me `password authentication failed for user "postgres"` error after running `docker-compose up`.

It used to run without any problems before recloning the project on the Ubuntu system and it still works without any problems on the Windows10 system.

My `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2'

services:
  postgresql:
    image: 'bitnami/postgresql:latest'
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    environment:
      - POSTGRESQL_USERNAME=someuser
      - POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword
      - POSTGRESQL_DATABASE=mydatabase
```

I tried `sudo docker system prune` to remove all stopped containers and their unused networks. This does not solve the problem.

What do I need to change/do so the Postgres image is able to run succesfully on the Ubuntu system again?

The full error:

```
postgresql_1  | nami    INFO  Initializing postgresql
postgresql_1  | postgre INFO  ==> No injected postgresql.conf file found. 
Creating default postgresql.conf file...
postgresql_1  | postgre INFO  ==> No injected pg_hba.conf file found. Creating default pg_hba.conf file...
postgresql_1  | postgre INFO  ==> Deploying PostgreSQL from scratch...
postgresql_1  | postgre INFO  ==> Creating database mydatabase...
postgresql_1  | postgre INFO  ==> Creating user "someuser"...
postgresql_1  | postgre INFO  ==> Granting access to "someuser" to the database mydatabase...
postgresql_1  | postgre INFO  ==> Configuring PostgreSQL...
postgresql_1  | postgre INFO  ==> Configuring replication parameters...
postgresql_1  | postgre INFO  ==> Configuring permissions for config files...
postgresql_1  | postgre INFO 
postgresql_1  | postgre INFO  
########################################################################
postgresql_1  | postgre INFO   Installation parameters for postgresql:
postgresql_1  | postgre INFO     User: someuser
postgresql_1  | postgre INFO     Password: ***************
postgresql_1  | postgre INFO     Database: mydatabase
postgresql_1  | postgre INFO   (Passwords are not shown for security reasons)
postgresql_1  | postgre INFO  
########################################################################
postgresql_1  | postgre INFO 
postgresql_1  | nami    INFO  postgresql successfully initialized
postgresql_1  | INFO  ==> Starting postgresql... 
postgresql_1  | 2019-04-15 09:31:18.582 GMT [125] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
postgresql_1  | 2019-04-15 09:31:18.583 GMT [125] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
postgresql_1  | 2019-04-15 09:31:18.587 GMT [125] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"
postgresql_1  | 2019-04-15 09:31:18.599 GMT [132] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2019-04-15 09:31:18 GMT
postgresql_1  | 2019-04-15 09:31:18.603 GMT [125] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
postgresql_1  | 2019-04-15 09:31:24.414 GMT [139] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
postgresql_1  | 2019-04-15 09:31:24.414 GMT [139] DETAIL:  User "postgres" has no password assigned.
postgresql_1  |         Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 95: "host     all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5"
postgresql_1  | 2019-04-15 09:31:27.492 GMT [140] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
postgresql_1  | 2019-04-15 09:31:27.492 GMT [140] DETAIL:  User "postgres" has no password assigned.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you check the documentation of the docker image (https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/postgresql) it says that when you set `POSTGRESQL_USERNAME` the postgres user won't have a password assigned and you won't be able to use it to login to the db.

Use the user that you specified.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In my `docker-compose.yml` I am using the user that I specified, yet it still tries to login as "postgres" user.

Comment: What do you mean by "yet it still tried to login as postgres"? What is trying to login as 'postgres'? The `POSTGRESQL_USERNAME` environment variable will tell the entrypoint script of the postgresql image to `create` a user with the name you entered. Then you have to use that user in your application or similar. It looks like you're trying to connect to the database using the `postgres` user.

Comment: I have a Django application that uses the database and user also used in the `docker-compose.yml`. After running `docker-compose up` I am able to connect to the database using my Django app.

Comment: Then you are able to connect? I don't understand what is the problem then.

Comment: The problem is that running `docker-compose up` on both Win10 and Ubuntu 18.04 resulted in the postgres db being setup and able to accept connections. However, after recloning the project on the Ubuntu system, running `docker-compose up` does not setup the db and is not accepting connections.

Comment: As per the logs you are showing and the amount of information at hand, I can see that everything is setup correctly. The entrypoint script created the user, the database and is ready to accept connections. But something is trying to access it by using the "postgres" user which is not possible per the docker image specifications. I suggest you re-check the configuration or code of your application to check that the credentials you're using are correct.

Comment: I used `POSTGRESQL_USER=postgres` and `POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD=admin` in the `environment` instruction and yet get this error and cannot connect to the database. Any idea?